# Short black and white animated cartoon about a dancing reindeer

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I've seen this maybe three times over the decades since about 1970 but it seems, from the animation type, to be many years older

What I remember:

Black and white, four minutes or so.
It starts off with a little cartoon  reindeer fourth-walling it at the viewer, then some music starts (NOT jingle bells, possibly Sleigh Ride) and it does a dance.
This takes place under a starry sky in what is presumably Santa's Village.

As it dances an elf or two come outside and join in, then another reindeer, then more "not remembers"

Santa appears but he's not the Coca Cola version, he has black hair and beard...he slightly resembles Bluto from Popeye the Sailor. He gives a big hearty laugh and then he turns to the fourth wall and repeats the laugh.

The music continues and all are dancing with the little reindeer in the centre, the cartoon fades away with Santa again laughing.

Note: previously asked on [SFF Chronicles](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/575178/) and further questions were raised...

Update: Dear all , please keep a special eye out on TV over this holiday period, one of us might get lucky and spot it!

Merry Christmas from Danny

Comment: Was it the sort of noodly arms and legs, constantly bouncing animation of the old cartoons like Boscoe or early Mickey Mouse?

Comment: Thinking back there maybe was a bit of that when the Santa elves joined the dancing

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=7C6NDwAAQBAJ) may help although I've already searched through the Google previews and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be from the short vintage Walt Disney b/w cartoon

.

The scene about 8 minutes in starts with a dancing reindeer and then more animals gather, but unfortunately I don't know the respective name of the cartoon to find out if Santa Claus also appears.

Comment: That clip is one of the early Disney Silly Symphonies shorts. It is called "Winter". Unfortunately Santa is not in it, just animals.

Comment: No sorry, not the scenes I remember, the reindeer was in a village or just outside the Santa workshop and that's where the elves came from to join in....thinking about the tune and it was (possibly!) Sleigh Ride. I've added that to my question